# Android Google Maps GeoJsonLayer OnFeatureClickListener, multiple layers

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick, geojson, layer

Please look at my code to create layer from geojson string and add layer to map:

```
private GeoJsonLayer createLayerFromGeojson(String json)
    {
        JSONObject ob = null;

        try
        {
            ob = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, ob);
        layer.addLayerToMap();

        layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(feature -> Utils.showMessage(getActivity(), "Clicked", feature.getProperty("description").toString()));

        return layer;
    }
```

Next add 2 layers to map:

```
String json = /*first geojson string here*/
String json2 = /*another geojson string here*/

createLayerFromGeojson(json);
createLayerFromGeojson(json2);
```

Problem: When I click on marker or pologon, always description taken from second json (json2) is displayed, even if I click on object created from first json, on first layer.

What's wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the documentation for the method `setOnFeatureClickListener` it says:

> Sets a **single click listener for the entire GoogleMap object**, that will be called with the corresponding Feature object when an object on the map (Polygon, Marker, Polyline) is clicked.

To me, it seems silly that we cannot have multiple layers with information from different GeoJson. It needs to be a MultiPolygon, MultiLineString or MultiPoint.

Reference: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/data/Layer.java#L89

Comment: Yes, it have already figured it out. I finally managed to add all my objects to single layer and my map contains only one, single layer.

Comment: How do you manage the click for individual Features using only one GeoJson? I am having problems when there is overlapping of features.

Comment: In short, I managed to extract all features from all geojsons I have. Then, add all extracted features to single layer on my map and set click listener for each feature

Comment: how you add multiple json file in single layer on map?

Comment: For those still struggling with this, here is a complete example of how to add multiple layers and handle their clicks.   https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/main/demo/src/gms/java/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/MultiLayerDemoActivity.java

Comment: The link of the previous comment isn't working, here is the working one: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/main/demo/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/MultiLayerDemoActivity.java