# I have multiple map layers from geojson. Need to get a click event from each one

Tags: android, google-maps

So I have 45 geojson files and I would like that each of them would have a different color which works.The next task which I have set for myself is that when I click on a layer it would display the district it was assigned by. Yet that doesn't work it only displays the last number which is 45 and it doesn't matter how I assign it.

[Android Google Maps GeoJsonLayer OnFeatureClickListener, multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017057/android-google-maps-geojsonlayer-onfeatureclicklistener-multiple-layers)
A similar question has been already asked. But I didn't get the answer.
How would I create MultiPolygons? What are features? 
Is it even possible to solve this task with a for loop or do I realy have to assign every by hand?

Also I imagine this task can be done with Polygons, can one get the latitude and longitude data from geojson files?

```
for(int i=1;i<=45; i++) {

    String fileNameTemp = "a" + i + ".geojson";
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open(fileNameTemp);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
                data = sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (data == null) return;
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(data);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (json == null) return;

            GeoJsonLayer geoJsonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, json);
            GeoJsonPolygonStyle geoJsonPolygonStyle = geoJsonLayer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();

            Random r = new Random();
            int color = r.nextInt(0xFFFFFF);
            int colorTransparent = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, 100);

            geoJsonLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new Layer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                    Log.d("district Nr.: ",i+"");
                }
            });
            geoJsonPolygonStyle.setStrokeColor(0);
            geoJsonPolygonStyle.setStrokeWidth(500);
            geoJsonPolygonStyle.setFillColor(colorTransparent);

            geoJsonLayer.addLayerToMap();
}
```

Comment: Solved it because I found this code. layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                Toast.makeText(GeoJsonDemoActivity.this,
                        "Feature clicked: " + feature.getProperty("mag"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

Comment: Thanks for letting us know you found a solution. Please consider answering your own question and accepting it for the community's sake. Thank you!